# Add string to clipboard java

Tags: java, eclipse, clipboard

I want to write a function that adds a string to the clipboard but when I run it I get the error: Error: Main method in class de.alpha.first.program.Boot not found. Define the main method as:
public static void main (String [] args):
or a JavaFX application must extend javafx.application.Application.
and when I add the function I cannot define the "copytoclip" function.
can you help with?

code:

```
package de.alpha.first.program;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;



public class Boot {

    public static void copytoclip(String thing) {
          StringSelection data = new StringSelection(thing);
          Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
          cb.setContents(data, null);  
      }




}
```

Comment: You need a main method with the header `public static void main(String[] args)` to run a Java program. You can't just run any method

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run the method directly.
first, add a main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

 copytoclip("This text will be copied to clipboard."); //Call your method. Pass parameters

}
```

Now everything inside the copytoclip will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your program lacks a main method. Try this:

```
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;

public class CopyToClipboard
{
    public static void copyToClip(String text)
    {
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(text);
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        copyToClip("Lorem Ipsum");
    }
}
```